# Javascript Function For Loop within function

Tags: javascript, for-loop

How to use a Standard *for* loop instead of *forEach* in below case?

I have written this code on paste of value in TextBox if length exceeds 4 character append it to next TextBox however my application doesn't Support IE8 foreach function hence i need a function which will run a normal for loop.

```
var inputsArray= new Array(4);
inputsArray[0] = document.getElementById("id1");
inputsArray[1] = document.getElementById("id2");
inputsArray[2] = document.getElementById("id3");
inputsArray[3] = document.getElementById("id4");

for (var i = 0, len = inputsArray.length;i < len; i++) {
  //some code
  fillTextFields(this.value,startingField);
}

function fillTextFields(code, startingField) {
  //***instead of forEach I need a normal for Loop how to do it?***
  inputsArray.slice(startingField).forEach(function (item, iter) {
    item.value = code.slice(iter * 4, iter * 4 + 4);
  });
}
```

Comment: your answer is in your question, you use a for loop just above

Comment: yes i already tried this code but creating a function within for Loop will not work how to call this function var x = inputsArray.slice(startingField); for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { function (item, iter) { item.value = code.slice(iter * 4, iter * 4 + 4); } }

Answer (score 0):

Since slice returns a new array, you should be able to just do (assuming startingField is an integer):

```
var x = inputsArray.slice(startingField);
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
...
}
```

Comment: yes i already tried this code but creating a function within for Loop will not work how to call this function 
var x = inputsArray.slice(startingField);
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    function (item, iter) {
        item.value = code.slice(iter * 4, iter * 4 + 4);
    }
}

Comment: in your for loop, "item" should be x[i] and "iter" should be i (using my variable names). So in this case you don't need the function; just do x[i].value = code.slice(i * 4...) Hopefully that gives you enough to fill in the body of the for loop.